# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: templates/entry.html

Tags: python-3.x

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/entry',method=['POST','GET'])

def entry():
    return render_template('entry.html',the_title='welcome to entry ')

@app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create your template files in the correct location; in the `templates` subdirectory next to your python module.

The error indicates that there is no `entry.html` file in the `templates/`directory. Make sure you created that directory in the same directory as your python module, and that you did in fact put a `entry.html` file in that subdirectory.

```
myproject/
  app.py
  templates/
    entry.html
```

If your app is a package, the `templates` folder should be created inside the package.

```
myproject/
   mypackage/
      __init__.py
      templates/
         entry.html
```